# Web Page Load Time: is it possible to know how long it will take for the page to fully load?

Tags: javascript, web-services

I came across [Piecon](http://lipka.github.io/piecon/),a tiny javascript library for dynamically generating progress pie charts in your favicons, I want to use it to display the page loading in the background.

Is it possible to get the load time value using javascript?

Thank you

Comment: No, there is no way to know on how long a page will take to load before it loads.

Comment: You might be able to initialize it before page load event and finish within page load event though. There is no way to know the time difference in advance or track progress

Comment: So, start time will be 0 and end time will be when the page has fully loaded, but how do i go about that